# We got 200mbps Fios internet, but speeds are half that

Tags: internet, internet-connection, internet-speed, fios

Since we got Verizon Fios internet, the speeds that they state on their website are wrong, because we payed for 200mbps but only getting 100mbps. Speedtest gives this result on every device that I use, even when I am standing right next to the Router. What is going on?

Comment: You have included no information at all on how you tested this. Is your ethernet capable of gigabit 1000BaseT, or only 100BaseT?

Comment: "Speedtest gives this result on every device .... "  <-- Contact your ISP as there is not enough information here and also, your ISP set it up.

Comment: It is 1000base t for the connection from the modem (ONT) to router. I used WiFi 5 (AC)

Comment: Update: Speedtest now averages 110 down and 120 up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked and our internet plan is 100/100 and the extra speeds are probably overprovisioning.